# How to parse string in python using library re ?

Tags: python, regex

I have the following strings, that should be parsed:

```
http_proxy=172.55.30.14:80
https_proxy=Administrator:some_password@172.55.30.27:443
```

I want to extract from this string

```
protocol = "http" (or "https")
proxy_server = 172.55.30.14
proxy_port = 80
```

and if password is set, variables username and password also should be initialized:

```
username = Administrator
password = some_password
```

I have an idea to split it using method split:

```
res = re.split(r':', line)
```

Any ideas how to do this better ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
import re

# s="""http_proxy=172.55.30.14:80"""
s="""https_proxy=Administrator:some_password@172.55.30.27:443"""

regex=r"^(?P<xprotocol>http[s]?)_proxy=((?P<xusername>\w+):(?P<xpassword>\w+)@)?(?P<xserver>[\d.]+):(?P<xport>\d+)"

res=re.match(regex,s,re.I)

print("protocol: {}".format(res.group("xprotocol")))
print("proxy_server: {}".format(res.group("xserver")))
print("proxy_port: {}".format(res.group("xport")))
print("username: {}".format(res.group("xusername")))
print("password: {}".format(res.group("xpassword")))
```

Some notes:
– `http[s]?` = `http` or `https`
– `\w` = one letter, include a->z, A->Z, 0->9 and _
– `+` = one or more. So `\w+` = one or more letters
– `(group)?`= zero or one text group
– `\d+` = one or more number, include 0->9

Comment: Not at all! Share knowledges is always a fun thing to do! :D